# Navigation bar image black

Tags: iphone, ios6

In my application i add custom navigation image while adding the remaining part of the image shows black in color, i used following code,

[image]

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar.png"];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarStyleDefault];
```

i want to show the back ground color in the in the black color part.what should change in code?

Comment: i think there is a problem in image ......

Comment: actual image is unshaped as per the design, is it posible to show the bakground color in tat black color part

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Following may be it works fine.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Edited**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Can you please make sure that image is proper or not?

Comment: Image is what that white color part in the naivation bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using very useful library (class **SCNavigationBar**) for styling navigaitonBar, [download it here](http://mixdesign.kz/SCNavigationBar.zip)

It supports all orientations, it works with no problem in my many apps.